# How to include shared examples without subject

Tags: ruby, rspec, capybara

I am using RSpec and Capybara. I want to test navigation panel with `click_link` with shared examples for concrete pages. But I can't use `it_should_behave_like` because I don't want to change subject after clicking links. Is there any way to include a shared example with `expect(page).to`?

EDIT:
Here is my code:

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe "SomeController" do

  subject { page }

  content_list = {
      home: 'Some text on the home page',
      about: 'Some text on the about page',
      order: 'Some text on the order page'
  }

  shared_examples_for 'with layout' do
    it { should have_content 'Some text on the layout' }
    it { should have_title 'Title' }
  end

  describe 'Home page' do
    before { visit root_path }
    it_should_behave_like 'with layout'
    it { should have_content content_list[:home] }
  end

  describe 'About page' do
    before { visit about_path }
    it_should_behave_like 'with layout'
    it { should have_content content_list[:about] }
  end

  describe 'Order page' do
    before { visit order_path }
    it_should_behave_like 'with layout'
    it { should have_content content_list[:order] }
  end

  it 'should have correct links on the layout' do
    visit root_path
    click_link 'Some link text'
    expect(page).to have_content content_list[:about]
    find('.logoLink').click
    expect(page).to have_content content_list[:home]
    click_link 'Another link text'
    expect(page).to have_content content_list[:about]
    click_link 'One more link text'
    expect(page).to have_content content_list[:order]
  end
end
```

I am checking the same things when visiting pages with route names and when visiting them clicking. I wanted to refactor it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`it_should_behave_like` doesn't implicitly change the subject, so you shouldn't have a problem per se.

For example, the following passes:

```
shared_examples "so" do
  it "should have access to variables from calling rspec scope" do
    expect(subject).to eql("foo")
    expect(page).to eql("bar")
  end
end

describe "so test" do
  let(:subject) {"foo"}
  let(:page) {"bar"}
  it_should_behave_like "so"
end
```

Given the code you shared, it's possible to reduce some duplication by passing a parameter to the shared example you have and introducing variables for each page's content. You can also make use of a lambda function to reduce duplication in the big, sequential example you have at the end. These techniques are shown below (not tested):

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe "SomeController" do

  subject { page }

  content_list = {
      home: 'Some text on the home page',
      about: 'Some text on the about page',
      order: 'Some text on the order page'
  }

  home_content = content_list[:home]
  about_content = content_list[:about]
  order_content = content_list[:order]

  shared_examples_for 'with layout' do |content|
    it { should have_content 'Some text on the layout' }
    it { should have_title 'Title' }
    it { should have_content content }
  end

  describe 'Home page' do
    before { visit root_path }
    it_should_behave_like 'with layout', home_content
  end

  describe 'About page' do
    before { visit about_path }
    it_should_behave_like 'with layout', about_content
  end

  describe 'Order page' do
    before { visit order_path }
    it_should_behave_like 'with layout', order_content
  end

  it 'should have correct links on the layout' do
    click_and_expect = lambda do |link_text, content|
      click_link link_text
      expect(page).to have_content content
    end
    visit root_path
    click_and_expect['Some link text', about_content]
    find('.logoLink').click
    expect(page).to have_content home_content
    click_and_expect['Another link text', about_content]
    click_and_expect['One more link text', order_content]
  end
end
```

However, to respond to one of your comments, I don't know how to easily eliminate the conceptual duplication between the `should have_content content` in the shared example and the `expect(page).to have_content content` in the final example. You can replace the former code with the latter code, since `page` is defined in both cases, but that still leaves you with the duplication of that string.

If you're willing to break up the sequential example at the end into a series of independent examples, then you can use a shared example across both. As is, though, the only way I know to share that code is through an `eval` of the same string.

Comment: I mean that subject must be changed after `click_link`, isn't it? But I don't want to do that explicitly and want to use `expect(page).to` instead of using subject.

Comment: No, `subject` is not changed after `click_link`, but independent of that, you can use `expect(page).to ...` in your shared example and count on `page` being evaluated in the rspec context in which it was called.

Comment: The question is HOW to call `it_should_behave_like` on `expect(page).to`?

`expect(page).to it_should_behave_like` doesn't work

Comment: Sorry, but I'm still not clear what you're asking. Is assumed the `expect` call would be in the shared example.

Comment: I want to call `expect(page).to it_should_behave_like 'something'`, but it doesn't work. I need a method like `it_should_behave_like` which would work with `expect(page).to`.

Comment: `it_should_behave_like` is not a _matcher_ or even an _expectation_. It corresponds to `it` and you can think of it as an alternative to `it`. So if you think of what you were previously going to put in your `it` block, think of invoking `it_should_behave_like` instead, providing whatever context you need (e.g. via `let`, a block or a parameter).

Comment: If you share the code you would have used without a shared example (e.g. two examples that have a lot in common), you can get help refactoring it to use a shared example.

Comment: `it { should have_content content_list[key]}` in `with layout` and `expect(page).to have_content content_list[:key]` in `basic page` is the repetiotion I want to remove and it's still there.

I actually want to remove `content_list` array which I created being unable to think off something better.

Comment: But why can't we use the `with layout` example inside this lambda instead of `expect(page).to have_content content` which repeats `it { should have_content content }` in the `with layout` example. It's either completely impossible or I completely fail to express my thoughts.

Comment: You can't invoke any of the methods which accept blocks (e.g. `describe/context`, `it_behaves_like` or `it`) from _within_ an `it` block. As I said in the last couple of paragraphs of my revised answer, you'd need to "break up" your last example into a set of independent examples in order to use a shared example.